# If what we eat can be seen in our hair, then to what degree can our food affect the "look and feel" of our hair?

Tags: human-biology, hair

It looks like most things (or everything?) that we consume, whether it is a food, drink, or something we smoke (like e.g. some drug like marijuana) ends up in some amounts in our hair.

If this is the case, is it theoretically possible that there exists some compound that, when ingested, could affect the color of our hair?

Or alternatively, would it be possible for an ingested chemical to weaken or strengthen the disulfide bonds present in hair structure?

Comment: It looks like? I'd be fascinated if you give a reference. I thought this is yet unproven theories....

Comment: @MARamezani, sorry, I do not have any references. This is just a thought that came to my mind and I was curious about whether it could be possible or not.